# PostgreSQL schema structuring

Tags: sql, postgresql, express, knex.js

This might be too broad a question but I'm building a blog app (Express/React/Postgres) and I'm new to the backend world.

I have tables for `users` and `posts` and if I want to track user reactions (thumbsup, smile, laugh, etc.) would you do that in the posts table or create a new `reactions` table with fkey references to users.id and posts.id?

I ask because I did the latter, then realized that posts can have multiple users and reactions, so I'm not sure the right / best way to do that, even with JOIN.

If it were JSON, this is how I see it in my mind, but I don't know how to translate this to SQL tables and knex queries.

```
[
  {
    "posts": [
      {
        "post_id": "1234567890ABCDEF",
        "content": "foo bar",
        "created_at": "01/18/2020",
        "reactions": {
          "users": [
            {
              "user_id": "D237NH23DGU6",
              "reaction": "thumbsup"
            },
            {
              "user_id": "DVSY8N8VSDYN6",
              "reaction": "angry"
            },
            {
              "user_id": "3D2J892D3J8933",
              "reaction": "laughing"
            },
            {
              "user_id": "23987DNHIUO8DD",
              "reaction": "thumbsup"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "post_id": "99FJ48FJ4F8JHSH",
        "content":  "bar foo",
        "created_at":  "01/18/2020",
        "reactions": {
          "users": [
            {
              "user_id": "DSDF879344FH97",
              "reaction": "sad"
            },
            {
              "user_id": "8S7DF62HF87H34F",
              "reaction": "peace"
            },
            {
              "user_id": "37HHF783H4K47834",
              "reaction": "laughing"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "post_id": "1234567890ABCDEF",
        "content":  "foo foo bar bar",
        "created_at":  "01/18/2020",
        "reactions": {
          "users": [
            {
              "user_id": "SDFWEF934949J4",
              "reaction": "thumbsup"
            },
            {
              "user_id": "R9TVU8TRVU89",
              "reaction": "angry"
            },
            {
              "user_id": "IJFG0F8GJ9",
              "reaction": "laughing"
            },
            {
              "user_id": "3F4V3NHVF43N8",
              "reaction": "thumbsup"
            },
            {
              "user_id": "VXDRTHVHM6D7",
              "reaction": "angry"
            },
            {
              "user_id": "A9SFDHSFDH78",
              "reaction": "laughing"
            },
            {
              "user_id": "DFSM8H87M9N",
              "reaction": "thumbsup"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a reactions table referring to the post, user, and their reaction is correct.

```
knex.schema.createTable('post_reactions', function(t) {
  t.integer('user').notNullable();
  t.foreign('user').references('id').inTable('users');
  t.integer('post').notNullable();
  t.foreign('post').references('id').inTable('posts');
  t.string('reaction').notNullable();

  t.unique(['user', 'post', 'reaction']);
}
```

The unique is so a user can only make a particular reaction once per post.

Getting the reactions to post 3 does not need a join.

```
knex('post_reactions')
  .select('user', 'reaction')
  .where('post', 3)
```

But maybe you want the user's names and the post's title.

```
knex('post_reactions')
  .join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'post_reactions.user')
  .join('posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_reactions.post')
  .select('posts.title', 'users.name', 'reaction')
  .where('post', 3)
```

---

I made it `post_reactions` both because they are reactions to a post (leaving room for reactions to something else), and because you may want to make a table for all possible reactions and join with that.

```
knex.schema.createTable('reactions', function(t) {
  t.increments();
  t.string('keyword').notNullable();
  t.unique('keyword');
}

knex.schema.createTable('post_reactions', function(t) {
  t.integer('user').notNullable();
  t.foreign('user').references('id').inTable('users');
  t.integer('post').notNullable();
  t.foreign('post').references('id').inTable('posts');
  t.integer('reaction').notNullable();
  t.foreign('reaction').references('id').inTable('reactions');

  t.unique(['user', 'post', 'reaction']);
}
```

Now we need an extra join if we want the reaction keyword in addition to the post's title and the user's name.

```
knex('post_reactions')
  .join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'post_reactions.user')
  .join('posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_reactions.post')
  .join('reactions', 'reactions.id', '=', 'post_reactions.reaction')
  .select('posts.title', 'users.name', 'reaction.keyword')
  .where('post', 3)
```

This has the advantage of ensuring every entry in `post_reactions` is a real reaction. Typos are not possible. It also means the keyword or other things about the reaction can change, but the reaction will still work.

Note that I avoided storing the reaction image itself in the database. You *can* do that, but it's often better to store assets on disk and refer to the file. This allows the assets to be directly linked to, reduces load on the database, and lets people work with the assets without having to touch the database.

Comment: Many thanks for your time. I'm going for Facebook style where a post can have thumbs up, angry, sad etc. AND counts for each of those and the associated user name for each reaction. What would knex query look like on the posts table, joining the users and reaction tables to return the right object to build out the posts list? Each post object would contain an array of reactions (`reactions.name`) and each of those would need an array of `users.display_name`.

Comment: @KirkRoss You can post-process the query results into your desired structure. Or you can use Postgres [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-aggregate.html) or get it to return [JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html). Best you ask that as a new question.

Comment: Cool... but if a third table is involved, wouldn't your `.join` example query above require an extra `.join` to pull in the `reactions` table?

Comment: @KirkRoss For the three table setup (posts, users, post_reactions), no, there is no separate reactions table; all information about a reaction is in post_reactions. For the four table setup (posts, users, post_reactions, reactions) if you want to get data out of the reactions table, like the keyword, yes. Add `.join('reactions', 'reactions.id', '=', 'post_reactions.reaction')`.